# How to output HTML '<div>' element with Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, input, output

I want a user to be able to enter specific values into an input field and would like to be able to output the values **WITH** HTML "markup" such as '< div >' and '< p >' as text only. I have tried outputting it as a string as well but i cannot figure it out. Please help!

I would like it to operate like this:

Input value = x
Output = x

does it have to be output as a string so the browser doesnt only output = x? All insight helps!

Please See My Example Here:

```html
<html>
<head>
  <title>Markup Generator</title>
</head>
<body>
 
First name: <input id="first_name">
Last name: <input id="last_name">
<button id="say">Say hi!</button>
 
<hr>
<div id="result"></div>
 
<script>
function say_hi() {
    var fname = document.getElementById('first_name').value;
    var lname = document.getElementById('last_name').value;
 
    var html = 'Hello <b>' + fname + '</b> ' + lname;
 
    document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = html;
}
 
document.getElementById('say').addEventListener('click', say_hi);
</script>
```

Comment: just replace innerHTML to innerText.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```html
<html>
<head>
  <title>Markup Generator</title>
</head>
<body>
 
First name: <input id="first_name">
Last name: <input id="last_name">
<button id="say">Say hi!</button>
 
<hr>
<div id="result"></div>
 
<script>
function say_hi() {
    var fname = document.getElementById('first_name').value;
    var lname = document.getElementById('last_name').value;
 
    var html = 'Hello <b>' + fname + '</b> ' + lname;
 
    document.getElementById('result').innerText = html;
}
 
document.getElementById('say').addEventListener('click', say_hi);
</script>
```

Comment: perfect! thats exactly what i needed. youre the best!

Answer (score 0):

You can use innerText instead of innerHTML
like this

```
document.getElementById('result').innerText = html;
```